# I am getting this error SAXParseException

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, xslt, xml-parsing

E org.apache.commons.digester.Digester error Parse Error at line 196 column 12: The content of element type "field" must match "(msg|arg0|arg1|arg2|arg3|var)*".
                                 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "field" must match "(msg|arg0|arg1|arg2|arg3|var)*".

My XML code is

```
<formset>
    <form name="groupCommForm">

        <field property="groupId" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.overCap.groupId"/>
        </field>

        <field property="subGroupId" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.overCap.subgroupId"/>
        </field>

        <field property="productCat" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.overCap.prodInd"/>
        </field>

        <field property="effDate" depends="required, date">
            <arg position="0" key="group.overCap.effDate"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
            </var>                        
        </field>

        <field property="termDate" depends="required, date">
            <arg position="0" key="group.overCap.termDate"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
            </var>                       
        </field>

        <field property="commType" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.overCap.commTyp"/>
        </field>

        <field property="changeReason" depends="required, maxlength">
            <arg position="0" key="group.overCap.comment"/>
            <arg position="1" name="maxlength" key="${var:maxlength}" resource="false"/>
            <var><var-name>maxlength</var-name><var-value>255</var-value></var>     
        </field>

    </form>

    <form name="asoForm">

        <field property="groupId" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.aso.groupId"/>
        </field>

        <field property="hlthDentInd" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.aso.hTDentInd"/>
        </field>

        <field property="subScriberCount" depends="required, integer">
            <arg position="0" key="group.aso.subscribCt"/>
        </field>

        <field property="premiumAmount" depends="required, float">
            <arg position="0" key="group.aso.premAmt"/>
        </field>

        <field property="dependnetCount" depends="integer">
            <arg position="0" key="group.aso.premAmt"/>
        </field>

        <field property="dueDate" depends="required, date">
            <arg position="0" key="group.aso.dueDate"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
            </var> 
        </field>

        <field property="changeReason" depends="required, maxlength">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.comment"/>
            <arg position="1" name="maxlength" key="${var:maxlength}" resource="false"/>
            <var><var-name>maxlength</var-name><var-value>255</var-value></var> 
        </field>

        <field property="asfProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.asf"/>
        </field>

        <field property="bmProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.bm"/>
        </field>

        <field property="commProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.comm"/>
        </field>

    </form>

    <form name="otherAdjForm">

        <field property="groupId" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.otherAdj.groupId"/>
        </field>

        <field property="subGroupId" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.otherAdj.subgroupId"/>
        </field>

        <field property="productCat" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.otherAdj.prodCat"/>
        </field>

        <field property="productInd" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.otherAdj.prodInd"/>
        </field>

        <field property="compMonth" depends="required, date">
            <arg position="0" key="group.otherAdj.compMonth"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
            </var> 
        </field>

        <field property="dueDate" depends="required, date">
            <arg position="0" key="group.otherAdj.dueDate"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
            </var> 
        </field>

        <field property="premium" depends="required, float">
            <arg position="0" key="group.otherAdj.premAmt"/>
        </field>

        <field property="commissions" depends="required, float">
            <arg position="0" key="group.otherAdj.comms"/>
        </field>

        <field property="asfProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.asf"/>
        </field>

        <field property="bmProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.bm"/>
        </field>

        <field property="commProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.comm"/>
        </field>

        <field property="changeReason" depends="required, maxlength">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.comment"/>
            <arg position="1" name="maxlength" key="${var:maxlength}" resource="false"/>
            <var><var-name>maxlength</var-name><var-value>255</var-value></var> 
        </field>

    </form>

    <form name="premEquiForm">

        <field property="groupId" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.premEqui.groupId"/>
        </field>

        <field property="subGroupId" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.premEqui.subgroupId"/>
        </field>

        <field property="productCat" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.premEqui.prodInd"/>
        </field>

        <field property="startDate" depends="required, date">
            <arg position="0" key="group.premEqui.startDate"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
            </var>
        </field>

        <field property="termDate" depends="required, date">
            <arg position="0" key="group.premEqui.termDate"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
            </var>
        </field>

        <field property="monthlyPremEquiAmt" depends="required, float">
            <arg position="0" key="group.premEqui.mnthlyPrem"/>
        </field>

        <field property="monthlyAccessFeeAmt" depends="required, float">
            <arg position="0" key="group.premEqui.mnthlyFee"/>
        </field>                    

        <field property="asfProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.asf"/>
        </field>

        <field property="bmProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.bm"/>
        </field>

        <field property="commProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.comm"/>
        </field>

        <field property="changeReason" depends="required, maxlength">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.comment"/>
            <arg position="1" name="maxlength" key="${var:maxlength}" resource="false"/>
            <var><var-name>maxlength</var-name><var-value>255</var-value></var> 
        </field>

    </form>

    <form name="usableForm">

        <field property="groupId" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.usable.groupId"/>
        </field>

        <field property="subGroupId" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.usable.subgroupId"/>
        </field>

        <field property="lifeDentInd" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.usable.lifeDentInd"/>
        </field>

        <field property="productInd" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.usable.prodInd"/>
        </field>

        <field property="methodologyType" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.usable.methType"/>
        </field>

        <field property="subScriberCount" depends="required, integer">
            <arg position="0" key="group.usable.subscribCt"/>
        </field>

        <field property="dependnetCount" depends="integer">
            <arg position="0" key="group.usable.depenCt"/>
        </field>

        <field property="dueDate" depends="required, date">
            <arg position="0" key="group.usable.dueDate"/>
            <var>
                <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
            </var>
        </field>

        <field property="premiumCashAmt" depends="required, float">
            <arg position="0" key="group.usable.premAmt"/>
        </field>

        <field property="asfProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.asf"/>
        </field>

        <field property="bmProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.bm"/>
        </field>

        <field property="commProcCode" depends="required">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.comm"/>
        </field>

        <field property="changeReason" depends="required, maxlength">
            <arg position="0" key="group.comm.comment"/>
            <arg position="1" name="maxlength" key="${var:maxlength}" resource="false"/>
            <var><var-name>maxlength</var-name><var-value>255</var-value></var> 
        </field>

    </form>

</formset>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but from the error, it sounds like the elements in `field` need to be named `msg`, `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`, or `var`. The numerous `arg`s you have don't match any of those.

Comment: Tahnks for your response JLRishe.. I changed but still getting errors.. The error line numbers are not fixed and are changing everytime I start the application..Can somebody please help me..

Comment: Please post your new code and related error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you are using struts? If it is so, try the simplest example ( like one here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Struts_Validation_in_validator.xml_using_an_ActionForm) and then try to add more fields, fitting your needs and see at which moment you get parser exception.

Anyhow you cannot use  elements and you cannot use more than one  you should rather use

```
<arg0>
<arg1>
```

than just

```
<arg>
<arg>
```